# How to run trigger after adding new table to database

Tags: mysql, triggers

i want to create one table in which all other table's information is stored e.g. table name and total fields of that table from same database.

So if there are 3 table in database in database 
Table 1: Student table with 13 column
Table 2: Teacher table with 10 column
i want table 3 which will have have data about other table so records in table 3 will be like

```
 1 | Student | 13
 2 | Teacher | 10
 3 | All_table | 3
```

if i create 4th table, Admin with 5 column
than trigger should add row to All_table

```
 1 | Student | 13
 2 | Teacher | 10
 3 | All_table | 3
 4 | Admin | 5
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Answer (score 0):

You dont need create a new table for that. In mysql you have:

- **[INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html)**
- **[INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html)**

  ```
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
    [AND table_schema = 'db_name']
    [AND column_name LIKE 'wild']
  ```

Comment: i think this will not help in my case, i am generating forms dynamically where i need to generate dropdown from other master table in that case i have to store some id to recognize that master table @Juan Carlos Oropeza

Comment: You have to show us an example. I still think this is the way to solve it, you have all the info there

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not currently support DDL triggers. Triggers are supported only for DML statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).

Whatever DML operations you need to perform (e.g. `INSERT INTO All_table`)  following the execution of a DDL statement (e.g. `CREATE TABLE`) would need to perform explicitly. MySQL can't run that automatically for you.

---

What problem is solved by maintaining `All_table`? i.e. Why does that table need to be populated?

Comment: i am generating forms dynamically where i need to generate dropdown from other master table's field in that case i have to store some id to recognize that master table in form detail table @spencer7593